# Unable to fetch data from workbench Mysql using node js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express, mysql-workbench

```
// import express js
const express = require('express')
// import a body-parser
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
// executing the express js
const app = express();
// import mysql packages
const mysql = require('mysql');
// use bodyparser in express
app.use(bodyparser.json);
// create an connection details for mysql database
var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
        host:'localhost',
        user:'root',
        password:'keerthi@abitech',
        database:'employeedb'
        
    }
)
// To connect with mysql database
mysqlConnection.connect((err)=>{
    if(!err)
    console.log('DB is connected')
    else
    console.log('DB connection is failed \n Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));

});

// establish an data fetch from database

app.get('/employees', (res, req)=>{
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM employee', (err, results)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(results);
        res.send("post is send")
    })
});


// creating an server
app.listen(3000, ()=>console.log("server is running in port number 3000"));
```

> This is my code. I am not able to fetch an data from mysql workbench.
> The page is loading only does not give any response.
> If i pass the link in postman it shows like this
> **Could Not Get Any Response**

Answer (score 0):

You are currently not sending your data back to the endpoint. Assuming that your connection is successful, you should `res.send(results)` instead of `res.send("post is send")` in order to send your results to the `/employees` endpoint.

Hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for your effort. Still now i am not able to get an data :(

Comment: I am getting like this "localhost didn’t send any data."

Comment: That is strange. Maybe double check to make sure you are hitting/requesting from the right endpoint. Also instead of res.send, use res.json so it treats the content a valid JSON object.

Comment: Ok thanks, is anything needed to configure in mysql workbench. I am new to backend. Thanks for your effort